# How can i replace icons from tree.store with glyphs in Extjs 4.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

Can someone give me an ideea how can i change default icons from tree.store extjs with glyphs  dynamicaly?
P.S i`m taking data ( root , leafs ) from json and i have a "type" property that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me. Tested on latest Chrome & Firefox, I think on IE it will not work as img content is not supported in IE.

1) Add font-awesome to your project

2) Sample iconCls  for a node:

```
iconCls: 'fa fa-th icon-content'
```

In your application's css:

```
.icon-content {
    content: "";
    background-image: none !important;
    margin-top: auto !important;

}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but doesn't work with Extjs 5.12.  Bummer.